# How to build a control chart of EWMA in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function to generate an EWMA graph similar to the one in the image.

[image]

I tried using using the library (qcc), but I didn't get the result.I'm new to this and I don't quite understand how the ewma chart works.

The values used μ=100,  σ=1 , k=2.859 and λ=0.2 .

```
test <-c(100.23,100.19,102.02,99.59,99.81,99.86,99.6,100.35,99.38,100.83,99.73,98,99.72,101.34,98.77,99.94,99.47,
99.95,100.33,99.57,100.82,100.23,100.68,101.64,100.86,99.28,101.41,100.21,101.85,101.43,103
)
v <- ewma(test,lambda = 0.2, nsigmas = 2.859 ,xlab="x",ylab="EWMA",std.dev = 1,center = 100)
```

[image]

Comment: *"didn't get the result"*, how so? the plot looks like it has all of the same components, plus extras. Is it just the "aesthetics" (colors, linetypes, legend/labels) that you're hoping to change?

Comment: I need to build an EWMA function to generate this graph.

Comment: *"need to build an EWMA function"*, if you need to write one yourself, then why bring up `qcc::ewma`? I infer that the plot is so "wrong" to you that you don't want to even try to change its behavior. You don't say "why" the plot is not good enough, and you demonstrate no effort, so it appears to me that you're asking for somebody to write it for you.

Comment: I wanted to know what to change to get to the graph. thanks

Comment: **Asking a third time**: _what **exactly** is wrong with the plot?_ Do you need to remove the stats at the bottom? (add `add.stats=FALSE`). Do you need to change the title? (add `title="..."`). Is it the UCL/LCL labels? (add `label.limits=c("A","B")` with whatever strings you want). Are the colors wrong? (Yeah, `qcc::ewma` is deficient here, no ability to affect any of the colors.) Do you want to remove the `+` points indicating raw data locations? (Again, deficient, no way to control with this func.)

Comment: I'll be candid Arion, I'm holding off on closing the question (needs clarity or focus) since you're new to SO. There are expectations of how questions are posed here, and first and foremost your question does not have enough information to really address your underlying need. You have sample data and the initial code (good!), which is above-average for first-questions, but you have not provided a clear problem-statement. On top of that, having to ask a question three times does not bode well. I'm willing to work with you, but you need to address the biggest gap in information.

Comment: English is not my main language, so I don't really know how to explain it. but it helped a lot thanks.

Comment: I understand and appreciate the challenge of communicating technical details in another language; while I know it's difficult, please communicate what you don't understand. Is my question clear? Are you able to at least crudely list what properties of the second plot in your question is not good?

Comment: I'm going to give up using this function and try another approach. thanks for helping me.

Comment: I suggest then that you delete this question (instead of editing it), since your revised method will be different enough that it warrants a new question (plus this question already has two votes against it). Having a question closed does not count against you; if you do nothing with this, I'll likely close it shortly to get it out of the way. Good luck!